# Creating enums with specific values/stored properties

Tags: swift, enums

I have a `CompassDirection` enum that I normally define in Java like so:

```
enum CompassDirection {
    N(0, 1), S(0, -1), E(1, 0), W(-1, 0), NE(1, 1), NW(-1, 1), SE(1, -1), SW(-1, -1)
    ...
```

Where the constructor expects `alterX` and `alterY` integer properties, stores them, and uses them in an `alter(Position position)` method like so:

```
public Position alter(Position pos) {
    return new Position(pos.x + this.alterX, pos.y + this.alterY);
}
```

**My goal** is to accomplish something similar in Swift. I can easily add an 8-case `switch` statement in my `alter()` method but this tends to add a lot more code and confusion.

This is what I tried in Swift:

```
enum CompassDirection {
    case N(0, 1), S(0, -1), E(1, 0), W(-1, 0), NE(1, 1), NW(-1, 1), SE(1, -1), SW(-1, -1)

    private let xAlter : Int
    private let yAlter : Int

    private init(_ xAlter: Int, _ yAlter: Int) {
        self.xAlter = xAlter
        self.yAlter = yAlter
    }

    func alter(position: XYPosition) -> XYPosition {
        return XYPosition(x: position.x + self.xAlter, y: position.y + self.yAlter)
    }
}
```

But Swift does not support stored properties in enums.

What is the most readable/Swifty solution for converting the above Java enum to a Swift enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Swift does not support stored properties in enums

You could make `xAlter` and `yAlter` computed properties. Here's a highly simplified example (only two cardinal directions):

```
enum CompassDirection {
    case n
    case s
    var alterX : Int {
        switch self {
        case .n: return 0
        case .s: return 0
        }
    }
    var alterY : Int {
        switch self {
        case .n: return 1
        case .s: return -1
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can add a method referring to `self.alterX` and `self.alterY`, exactly as you desire.

Comment: Thanks Matt, suspicions confirmed.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "suspicions confirmed". This is the _exact_ Swift equivalent of your Java code. We are supplying each case with _constant property values_. It's just that the notation is slightly different. This is in marked contrast to putting a switch in `alter`, where we have to execute the switch _every time `alter` is called_.

Comment: I simply mean there's no way to accomplish this without an exhaustive switch. It's possible in Java because the enums can shorthandedly be constructed with the x/y alter arguments. (See the Java implementation of `alter()` in my question.) Since Swift doesn't support stored properties in enums, a switch is the only route.

Comment: Agreed. My point was merely that your Java and my Swift are two shorthands for exactly the same thing. You won't find me arguing that Swift's shorthand is "better"! But in the end — and this I _do_ argue — it just comes down to where on the page you write the magic numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @matt for the computed property idea, I like the creativity. This is another solution using an exhaustive `switch`:

```
enum CompassDirection {
    case N, S, E, W, NE, NW, SE, SW

    func alter(position: XYPosition) -> XYPosition {
        var xAlter : Int = 0
        var yAlter : Int = 0

        switch(self) {
            case CompassDirection.N:
                yAlter = 1
            case CompassDirection.S:
                yAlter = -1
            case CompassDirection.E:
                xAlter = 1
            case CompassDirection.W:
                xAlter = -1
            case CompassDirection.NE:
                xAlter = 1; yAlter = 1
            case CompassDirection.NW:
                xAlter = -1; yAlter = 1
            case CompassDirection.SE:
                xAlter = 1; yAlter = -1
            case CompassDirection.SW:
                xAlter = -1; yAlter = -1
        }

        return XYPosition(x: position.x + xAlter, y: position.y + yAlter)
    }
}
```